# I have build issue in TFS. I have recently modified build services in Team Administration control.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have build issue in TFS. I have recently modified build services in Team Administration control.  But When I am trying to build its giving me the following error Exception Message: Access to the path 'C:\Builds\41\Legacy\LegacyScoring_DEV_Build\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\AI.Services.FraudGuardScoringZone.Web_Package\AI.Services.FraudGuardScoringZone.Web.zip' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteFile(String path, Boolean throwExceptionOnFailure) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryInternal(String path) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryInternal(String path) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectoryInternal(String path) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.DeleteDirectory(String path, Boolean recursive) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.DeleteDirectory.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? TFS 2012? Please elaborate what have you changed in Administration Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the account of run build service, you need to check the permission of this account. A build server can build and test code in a team project collection only if the build service account is a member of the **Project Collection Build Service Accounts** group of that collection.

Also, try to clean the cache folders on both your local machine and TFS AT machine:

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache. (x is the version of TFS)
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0